# Verification of form

Tags: forms, validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

 function verifyForm()

{

  if( document.forms[0].age.value < 18 || >30)

    { 
      alert(" The age input is not valid.");
      return false;
    }

   alert("Form is valid");
   return true;

}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body>

Enter the following information. Fields denoted with a * are required.

<form action="" method="post" name="aform">

<table>

<tr><td>Enter first name</td><td><input type="text" name="first" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter last name</td><td><input type="text" name="last" />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your age</td><td><input type="text" name="age" size="5" />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your sex</td><td><input type="text" name="sex" size="2" />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your favorite color</td><td><input type="text" name="color" /></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="verify();" /></td></tr>

</table></form>
```

I'm trying to verify these forms but whenever I click on the button to verify them nothing happens. Can you help me as to why nothing is happening?

Comment: `document.forms[0].age.value < 18 || >30` --- where did you find such syntax? You have just written it as you pronounce "if age value is less than 18 or more than 30"?

Comment: Actually, what that says is something to the effect of "`Unexpected token >`"

Comment: What browser are you using to test with? Most (all?) the browsers these days have a javascript console which will help you debug your problems. This is an invaluable tool when developing javascript.

Comment: @zerkms shouldn't it be like that if i want the number to be between 18 aand 30

Comment: @jonathan miller: why do you think it should?

Comment: @jonathanmiller Ok, so in Chrome if you click on the `wrench > tools > Javascript console` the javascript console will pop up at the bottom of your browser window. If you select the 'console' tab you should get warning and error messages explaining when javascript encounters problems.

Comment: @zerkms that is what i found on the internet and i used it for another page i did and it worked there

Comment: @jonathan miller: nope, it couldn't work, it is so incorrect :-)

Comment: @David thanks for that. I did that and it said that the <18 || >30 is an unexpected token as well verifyForm not being defined. I'm not sure what to do as far as fixing those

Comment: @jonathanmiller I'm not really interested in troubleshooting your code. You now have a new tool to find your problems. One of your problems is your syntax for comparing between 18 and 30 as zerkms is trying to explain. The other is probably a typo, or where/how you have defined the function is wrong. You can now do some googling on each individual problem as you know what they are.

Comment: @David thanks for the help i found the error through the tools and it works now

Comment: @zerkms the problem was with the syntax that you said. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not working because your function is called `verifyForm()` but your button has `onclick="verify();"`

It should be `onclick="verifyForm();"`

**Javascript console in Chrome:**
In Chrome if you click on the `wrench > tools > Javascript console` the javascript console will pop up at the bottom of your browser window. If you select the 'console' tab you should get warning and error messages explaining when javascript encounters problems.

Comment: This is definitely one of your problems. @zerkms is onto the other one. You may have more, and the javascript console will help you find those.